# SSL certificate for EC2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway, devops, aws-cli

How can I get a SSL certificate for my EC2 instance that is running on Ubuntu.
I've read this tutorial: [Tutorial: Configure Apache Web Server on Amazon Linux 2 to Use SSL/TLS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-an-instance.html) , but of no help.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Where are you getting stuck?  What error messages or symptoms are you getting?  Check out [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting the help you need.

Comment: I can get SSL certificate for a Domain, but is it even possible to get a SSL certificate for EC2 instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't configure it via some backend. You have to manage them on your own, which means, you have to place all needed files (key and cert) in some directory and load them from there into your application. You should look for a framework/language-specific guide (Apache, Node.js, etc.).

Edit: It looks like the AWS Certificate Manager does now support also partially EC2 (didn't earlier):

> You can use private certificates issued with ACM Private CA with EC2
>   instances, containers, and on your own servers. At this time, public
>   ACM certificates can be used only with specific AWS services.

If you want to know how to do this exactly, please open a new question, which addresses the AWS Certificate Manager. I personally do prefer hosting independent solutions and would recommend you to do the same.

Comment: AWS' Certificate Manager can't help me with this?

Comment: I edited the question and pointed it out, do you already have a certificate bought or do you plan to use some free service?

Comment: ACM Private CA is not relevant for this use case.

Comment: I can get SSL certificate for a Domain, but is it possible to get a SSL certificate for EC2 instance?

Comment: Yes of course. I think you have a basic misunderstanding about EC2 instances. (Not fully correct, but for better understanding I won't get into the details): Consider it just as some kind of virtual machine which is running in the cloud. It's just an OS, like the one you are using, you can do everything with it, there are no limits except resource limits. However, adding SSL certificates should be considered a web server thing and not an OS / cloud service thing. You just need to configure your Apache right: https://geekflare.com/apache-setup-ssl-certificate/